# HTML - Buttons and Input

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web-page out of HTML and whenever I hit one of the buttons, it clears all the text in my inputs. When I hit one of the buttons, I only want it to clear the text in its div. How do I do this? This is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SmartMail</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1><b>Welcome to SmartMail!!</b></h1>
    <form>
      <div class="recipients">
        <input type="text" class="typer">
        <br><br>
        <button class="ar">Add User</button>
        <button class="ur">Remove User</button>
        <br><br><br>
        <select name="users" class="userlist" size="24">
          <option class="listhead"> __________*Recipents*__________
          </option>
          <option class="listhead">-------------------------------
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <button class="send">Send</button>
        <br><br>
        <textarea name="content" class="typec" cols="113" rows="12"> 
                    </textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is always refreshing when your click on any of the buttons because a `button` tag inside a `form` tag is interpreted as a submit button (`<button type="submit">`). You need to explicitly give the buttons a type of `button`. You will also need to prevent the default action when enter is pressed in an `input` with `event.preventDefault()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SmartMail</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1><b>Welcome to SmartMail!!</b></h1>
        <form>
            <div class="recipients">
                <input type="text" class="typer" id="typer">
                <br><br>
                <button type="button" class="ar">Add User</button>
                <button type="button" class="ur">Remove User</button>
                <br><br><br>
                <select name="users" class="userlist" size="24">
                    <option class="listhead"> __________*Recipents*__________ 
                    </option>
                    <option class="listhead">------------------------------- 
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>   
            <div class="content">
                <button type="button" class="send">Send</button>
                <br><br>
                <textarea name="content" class="typec" cols="113" rows="12"> 
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('typer').addEventListener("keypress", (e)=>{
      if(e.keyCode==13){
       e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Wait, but if you hit the enter key in the text input, we have the same problem. How do I get rid of that

Comment: @Terabyte I have fixed that problem.

Comment: No, I meant pressing the enter key. I press it and it acts like "submit"

Comment: @Terabyte Did you try pressing it in the code snippet?

Comment: Oh but in the in chrome, the enter thing works. Maybe it is a chrome thing. If it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: @Terabyte I'm using Chrome, and the enter key does not submit the form. Perhaps you could just `return false` when the form submits.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Terabyte Change the start of your `form` tag to this: `<form onsubmit="return false;">`. However, this will prevent the form from ever submitting. You probably want some event handler to conditionally prevent the form submission.

Comment: I want to type some javascript code so that when I press "add user", the email in the text input gets added to the visible, scroll list. I also want to email all the users in the list when I press "send". With "return false", do you think that that is still feasible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176905/discussion-between-hev1-and-terabyte).

Comment: Oh and I don't have a form tag. I have a div tho.